# Google Script to copy and archive Form Responses in New Sheet on Weekly Basis

Tags: javascript, google-sheets, archive

So I'll start out by saying I just started learning Javascript 4 days ago. Now that that's out of the way, my intention with this script.

I'd like to automate the process of moving Google Form Responses, which are collected in a spreadsheet, to a new sheet within the same workbook as an archive.

I'd like this to happen on a weekly basis, and for each archive sheet that is created to have only 1 weeks responses. This should be between 12:01AM-1:00AM on Sundays, it really doesn't matter during that hour when it happens.

I would also like to then delete all of those responses from the primary collection sheet(Current_Responses), but if I have to manually delete these later it's fine (and probably good, because then I can review that the script worked properly).

I feel like I have a pretty solid start on doing this, but since I am new to all this, I would really appreciate it if a more experienced scripter could look over my code and tell me if this will work how I intend it to, and if not, where the mistakes are and how to correct them. I'm happy to make mistakes, and then learn from them so any advice will be deeply honored.

I researched several topics and scripts across three websites to help put this together. Thanks in advance for any help and advice!

```
// function to copy from Current_Responses to new sheet 'Archived_Responses
//(UTC Date)' placed after Current_Responses
function CreateCopySheetWeekly() {

  //source info
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Current_Responses');
  var range = ss.getRange ('A:I'); //replace column length as needed
  var data = range.getValues ();

  //creates target sheet to copy responses to
  var ts = 'Archived_Responses '+formatDate();
  ss.insertSheet(sheetName, ss.getSheets().length, {template: templateSheet});
  ts.getRange(ts.getLastRow()+1, 1, data.length, data[0].length).setValues(data);
}
//end of primary function

//function to determine and format UTC Date for CreateCopySheetWeekly function
function formatDate() {
  var month, day, d = new Date();
  month = ('0'+(d.getUTCMonth()+1)).slice(-2);
  day = ('0'+(d.getUTCDate()).slice(-2);
  return d.getUTCFullYear()+'-'+month+'-'+day;
}
//end of date function

//check every hour to determine when to perform newSheetLast function. Intended for Sunday
//between 0001-0100
window.setInterval (onSunday(){
  var today = new Date();
  if (today.getDay() == 0 && today.getHours() === 12) {
  CreateCopySheetWeekly();
}, 600000);
```

Go easy on me since I am new at this, but constructive criticism never hurt anyone.

Answer (score 0):

If you run this once a week we can make the simplifying assumption that you want all responses backed up once a week and then clear the main response sheet.

Let's go through the functions step by step and optimize it.

First of all you are already getting all rows, if you want all data you can just `getDataRange()` and not have to worry about extending.
Also we won't need the actual data.

```
function CreateCopySheetWeekly() {

  //source info
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Current_Responses'); // Current Responses
  var range = ss.getDataRange();
```

`formatDate()` is just creating a ISO8601 representation of the current date if I understand correctly so you can remove the function and instead use

```
var ts = 'Archived_Responses '+ new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);
```

Insert sheet with a template already copies all the data so you only need

```
ss.insertSheet(ts, ss.getSheets().length, {template: templateSheet});
```

Then we want to clean up our main response sheet.
If we just clear the range the form will keep appending after what would be the last row if we had never cleared because it remembers how many responses it got so we need to delete all rows but the headers.

```
templateSheet.deleteRows(2, range.getNumRows() - 1);
```

Making the final script

```
function CreateCopySheetWeekly() {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var templateSheet = ss.getSheetByName('Current_Responses'); 
  var range = ss.getDataRange(); 
  var ts = 'Archived_Responses '+ new Date().toISOString().slice(0,10);

  ss.insertSheet(ts, ss.getSheets().length, {template: templateSheet});
  templateSheet.deleteRows(2, range.getNumRows() - 1);
}
```

Lastly you can schedule it by going to Resources > Current Project's Triggers and set up a time based trigger.